# Hard drive spins for 1-2 sec's and stops and tickling sound is audible and drive not detecting

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Seagate Barracuda 7200.12 500gb hard drive. It was making a tickling sound so I thought it was a HDD problem and opened the drive and remove the head and put it back it shows once in Device Manager and again nothing.

I tried to fix the heads but not worked anything. Later I checked my PC with another HDD and it also struggles to power up.

Then I realized it's a SMPS problem later, I replaced the SMPS but right now the seagate barracuda 7200.12 drive spins when powered up and stops after a 1-2 seconds and the tickling sound is clearly audible.

Is it a PCB problem or what? I put this PCB in other 160gb hard drive it did the same spin and stop.

I bought another new Seagate pipeline 500gb HDD and luckily its PCB number same as old.

Should I replace the rom ic and try with the new board or can I replace the new hard drive head to old one or its better to platter swap.

I want to recover data from the old drive and can't afford to hire a professional data recovery analyst.

Comment: That drive is dead by now. You also took it apart on a non-laboratory conditions so the hard drive is not on vaccum anymore preventing it from working correctly.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Hard drives do not contain a vacuum. They *require* air in order to operate, and (apart from newer helium drives) not even isolated air: there's a filtered path. That said, any and all dust that would've gotten in would be very bad. And physically manipulating the arms? Yea, that drive's beyond toast.

Comment: @Bob indeed haha, i meant with vaccum like what's inside doesn't go out, of course it needs air to operate.

Comment: Next time, before opening it, maybe try a software solution like SpinRite - it's not a big drive(terrabytes) so SpinRite shouldn't have any trouble seeing it correctly...

Answer (score 3):

Ticking drive == failed drive.

It was already failing. Taking it apart yourself just removed any chance whatsoever of being able to fix it.

If the data is valuable & you have no backup, then search for a data recovery specialist. They are expensive & will make no guarantees of success. They might have had more chance had you not already exposed it to unfiltered air.

Comment: *Taking it apart yourself just removed any chance whatsoever of being able to fix it.* There are malfunctions when the disk can be repaired. For example, if they are associated with bad contact between logic board and HDA.

Comment: @Akina ‘opened the drive & removed the head’ == dead as a dodo

Comment: Open the drive? where I said to open its HBA (sealed chamber, filled with clean, dust-free air and containing a pack of magnetic disks and the magnetic heads)? If you carefully remove the logic board (LB), unscrewing the screws, clean and lubricate the contacts between the LB and the HBA, and then return everything to the place, then there is a chance that the problem will disappear.

Comment: If the drive had been taken to a data recovery professional when the problems first appeared the chances are good that most data could have been recovered. That is the typical case. But after the abuse the drive has now suffered I don't think an honest professional would even look at it. It would be a waste of his time and your money. Removal of the drive heads without the proper tools and procedures will almost certainly damage them. This is all far more complex then you imagine.