# Recover data from damaged Hard Drive (Windows)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, recovery, scratch

My external hard drive wasn't working, so I looked online and followed a very suspicious tutorial, openned it and the disk had some marks, like if the reader head was "scratching" the surface.
I cleaned it with isopropyl alcohol 99,8% pure, closed it and tried again, but the sound was still there and when I openned the disk had the same marks across the surface.
I know this hard drive is lost, but I need to recover around 500mb of data from it.
I know I'm probably wrong, but since the HD is 1TB and the data I need is around 500MB, so there is the possibility that the data I want is still undamaged, since it is about 0,5% of the disk.

Anybody has any idea of what to do to stop the head from marking the surface of the disk?
The hard drive appears when I use Easeus data Recovery, but it stays in 0% forever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hard drive spins for 1-2 sec's and stops and tickling sound is audible and drive not detecting](https://superuser.com/questions/1439765/hard-drive-spins-for-1-2-secs-and-stops-and-tickling-sound-is-audible-and-drive)

Comment: It's not much different from that question and because you opened the harddrive, there is a [little chance](https://superuser.com/a/1439768/880618) of recovering data out of it.

Answer (score 1):

If the heads are scratching the disk platter they are likely damaged and would need to be replaced. If the drive is making ticking noises this would be further confirmation. Replacing the heads is a lot more difficult than it might seem. HD manufacturers do not sell parts so they would have to come from a closely matched doner drive. Successful replacement requires special tools and following specific procedures, and a lot of practice. Most amateur attempts have failed and have only resulted in further damage.

If the drive had been taken to a recovery professional when the problem first developed it is likely that most data could be recovered. Most companies have a policy that there is no charge if no data is recovered. That does not apply if the drive has been opened, if they will accept the drive at all.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you opened up the drive in a "clean room" then you probably destroyed all chance of recovering anything.  There are companies who are able to retrieve data from physically damaged hard drives.  I had to to use one many years ago when I had a disk crash.  It is not cheap and will not recover all data.